# Concatenate data in Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, callback

I have two `javascript` functions.

This is one function and other one is also same.

```
function function1(.., .., callback){
    //database logic

 callback(data);

}
```

My requirement is to get data from both functions and send to client side.

```
function sendFunction(){

   function1(.., .., function(data1)){
      console.log(data1);
   }

   function2(.., .., function(data2)){
      console.log(data2);
   }

   sendToClient(data1+data2);
}
```

My issue is how can I take outside data1 and data2 from functions to concatenate. Guide me to achieve this task.

Comment: are you returning `data1` and `data2` from both the functions?

Comment: using callbacks for both functions

Comment: did you print `console.log(data1, data2)` ?

Comment: yes,  console.log(data1) and console.log(data2)  works fine. 
console.log(data1 + data2) returns empty.

Comment: returns empty means does it return `undefined` or anything else ?

Comment: Data is JSON Objects

Comment: And you try to simply add???????

Answer (score 2):

Considering that `function1` and `function2` are synchronous, you have to create two variables outside the functions to store the returned values.

```
function sendFunction () {
    var data1, data2;

    function1(.., .., function(d1) {
        data1 = d1;
        console.log(data1);
    });

    function2(.., .., function (d2) {
        data2 = d2;
        console.log(data2);
    });

    sendToClient(data1 + data2);
}
```

**EDIT:**

For async functions, I suggest you to use Promises:

```
function function1 () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // logic here

        // If everything is ok, call resolve().
        resolve("data1");

        // If something went wrong, call reject().
    });
}

function function2 () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // logic here

        // If everything is ok, call resolve().
        resolve("data2");

        // If something went wrong, call reject().
    });
}

function sendFunction () {
    Promise.all([function1(), function2()])
    .then(function (result) {
        sendToClient(result[0] + result[1]);
    })
    .catch(function () {
        console.log("The request failed. Try again.")
    });
}

sendFunction();
```

Comment: With promises, you should just use `Promise.all`. Outer-scope variables are a horrible practice.

Comment: @Bergi Fixed. I used to use jQuery's `$.when()`. I'm still getting used to JavaScript Promises. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, +1 :-) The updated version also has the benefit of running the two requests in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Do sth like:

```
var datas=[];
var count=0;
function callback(data){
count++;
datas.push(data);
if(count==2){
//perfect both callbacks returned
proceedwith(datas);
}
}
function1(callback);
function2(callback);
```

If they are json objects, you cannot add them. Store them into an array, or inside of an object, or stringify them

Comment: In here I intepreted what I need to do. You are correct. I need array to store two objects. but that is not the issue in here

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a way to do this.

```
function sendFunction () {      

    function1(.., .., function(data1) {
        console.log(data1);

        function2(.., .., function(data2) {
           console.log(data2);

            sendToClient(data1 + data2);
        });
    });


    sendToClient(data1 + data2);
}
```

Comment: This is not a good way because it includes nesting. If you have more than 2 functions, it becomes complicated. Please, check my updated answer using the new JavaScript Promises.

Comment: You don't need to use `var data1, data2` and those assignments. Just go for `function(data1) {` and `function(data2) {` directly.